# Load configuration for angular ngmodule

Tags: angular, configuration, angular-module

I am loading config data in `platformBrowserDynamic` like that:

```
 platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: MyConfig, useValue: new MyConfig(data.config) }])
```

`MyConfig` is a class:

```
export class MyConfig {
  setting1: string;
  setting2: string;
  other: {}

  constructor(data: any) {
   this.setting1 = data.setting1;
   this.setting2 = data.setting2;
   this.other = data.other;
  }
}
```

My `MyCustomModule`

```
    export function someFactoryTest() {
     debugger; //<--got debugger steps here
     return 'something';
    }

   export function initializeConfig(config: MyConfig) {
     debugger; //<--debugger does not steps here and no errors in console.
     return config.other;
    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        MyOtherModule.forRoot(initializeConfig, someFactoryTest) //<-- I want to be able to pass my params here
      ],
    })
    export class MyCustomModule {}
```

I can not getting the values form `MyConfig`, tried to debug but interestingly the debugger does not steps in to `initializeConfig` at all

Do you have any ideas how to approach that?

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @benshabatnoam I want to be able to to pass parameters from the outside to my module `MyOtherModule.forRoot(initializeConfig, someFactoryTest)`